# Why I am getting error saying must have writable analog variable or name.field for this argument "SQL connect"?

Tags: sql-server, scada-ignition

Why I am getting error when I try to connect with SQL server database by writing "SQL connect" command in action script in intouch SCADA saying must have writable analog variable or name.field for this argument "SQL connect"?

Command used

```
Result Code = SQL Connect (ConnectionID,"DSN=intouch");
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error that you are encountering?